# How to show data from ASP.NET Web Application to Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want all the records created in ASP.NET Web Application to be shown in my Mobile App Xamarin.Forms. What's happening to my program is that I was able to create records in my Web Application and save it, but I wasn't able to make it appear in my Xamarin.Forms Mobile app. I have created a MainViewModel that will get the records from the Web Application which I have binded to my MainPage.
These are my codes:

MainPageMain.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp"
         x:Class="XamarinDemoApp.MainPageMain"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinDemoApp"
         BackgroundColor="Teal"
         Title=" Title Bar">



 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
     <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
 </ContentPage.BindingContext>


 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                  FontSize="24"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding Department}"
                  FontSize="24"/>

        </StackLayout>

      </ViewCell>

      </DataTemplate>

     </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

   <Label Text="This is the MainPage"/>

 </StackLayout>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinDemoApp.Models;
using XamarinDemoApp.Services;

namespace XamarinDemoApp.ViewModels
    {
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private List<Employee> _employeesList;

    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get { return _employeesList; }
        set
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
      InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
     {
         var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();
         EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
     }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate API controller that you can use to call EmployeeList as a JSON object. That is the preferred way to do this kind of thing. Example:

```
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<List<Employee>> Get()
   {
      return await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();

   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sort of. I would be careful to break the Single Reponsability Pattern and do all the database related stuff directly inside a controller, but yeah, that's basically it. Additionally, you should make your website subscribe to the same API instead of duplicating code. Once completed, you get the data from the ApiController, exactly like your Xamarin app does.

Comment: That's what I did. That content of the link i provided is my actual code but still, it didn't work. I'm just a newbie here so maybe you can take a look at my code. Sorry sir.

Comment: Can you include your Employee class? Is it marked as Serializable?

Comment: Is this class you are referring to? This is the Employee.cs http://pastie.org/10857695#9 Or you're looking for my EmployeesServices class? http://pastie.org/10857698

Comment: That was the one, it's not marked with [Serializable] or [DataContract], so in essence, Visual STudio does not know how to serialize it to JSON so you can consume it on the other end. Just add one of them (and corresponding namespace) to the top of the class and you should be golden

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113295/discussion-between-jaycee-evangelista-and-pedro-g-dias).